# Java - Getting specific folder and files from zip file

Tags: java, android

So I am working on an Android app and what I am trying to do is make it so a user selects a zip file, it extracts the contents of it into an apk and installs the modified APK for the user. Right now all the files in the zip file have to be in the root of the zip file for it to work, if there is a directory and than the files I need it will not work. I am trying to make it scan for, for example the 'assets' folder and than get the directory its located in and copy all the files from that directory. I've tried extracting the files first and scanning using a loop, and for some reason had no success doing that, and it was time consuming anyways. If you know any libraries or could point me in the right direction that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Why would you have a zip file with your .apk contents? Why not just have an .apk file...

Comment: why you are not uploading your apk to Google play store. User will notify easily when ever you upload your updated application apk.

Answer (score 1):

BTW you can extract all the files from zip folder like below. i.e

```
private String unpackZip(String path, String zipname) {
        String apkfilename = "";
        InputStream is;
        ZipInputStream zis;
        try {
            String filename;
            is = new FileInputStream(path + "/" + zipname);
            zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
            ZipEntry ze;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

                filename = ze.getName();

                // Need to create directories if not exists, or
                // it will generate an Exception...
                if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                    File fmd = new File(path + "/" + filename);
                    fmd.mkdirs();
                    continue;
                }
                // This condition is to only extract the apk file
                if (filename.endsWith(".apk")) {
                    apkfilename = filename;
                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path + "/"
                            + filename);

                    while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }

                    fout.close();
                    zis.closeEntry();
                }
            }
            zis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return apkfilename;
        }
        return apkfilename;
    }



  //To install the apk file call the method 
       String apkfilename=unpackZip(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath(), "temp.zip");


    try {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getPath(), apkfilename);
            Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(
                    Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(promptInstall);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//Also add the read write permission 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```